# Python Argparse without command keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

So, what i am trying to do is LS Mimic in Python code.

I have completed most of the commands, but i have one thing that i cant find the solution

So, if the `ls` command gets this command line,

`ls test1`

It should find the `test1` directory and then do the `ls` in that directory.

However, since I can only find ways of creating arguments that needs a keyword before the 
actual usage, I cant find the way of doing this..

it cant be something like this

`ls -move_dir test1`

it is fine if for the program to think if there is no command, it will treat as above way.
( it will find that directory and run `ls` )

Please help me !!

Comment: `argparse` supports [positional arguments](http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags).

Comment: Oh yea but i forgot to mention that positional argument is when you have to have that argument. but in the above case, that is not correct. anyways thanks!

Comment: The answer you've accepted is using a _positional argument_. I supposed I could have mentioned that you needed to look into using the `nargs` parameter _in addition_ to using a _positional argument_... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this help?

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('a', nargs='*')
res = p.parse_args()
print res.a
```

Result:

```
% python test.py 1 2 3
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score -2):

try looking into using `sys.argv[]`

Comment: Ugh.. it could work but i already have implemented everything in argparse and i like the way argparse works.. but thanks for the reply